# How to Create a Rule in Outlook Using Python Based on Subject

Tags: python, python-3.x, vba, outlook, win32com

I am using Python 3.x and I am trying to create a rule in Outlook based on the text in the subject line. Here is my code so far:

```
...
o = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
rules = o.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
rule = rules.Create(zapNumber, 0)
    
condition = rule.Conditions.Subject
condition.Text = ['Foo', 'Bar']
condition.Enabled = True
...
```

I am getting an error:

```
condition.Text = ['Foo', 'Bar']
  File "******************************************************\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 284, in __setattr__
    object.__setattr__(self,
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', ('Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again.', 'Microsoft Outlook', None, 0, None))
```

I am not sure if there is a way around setting the Text property and why it won't take anything I try.

Comment: This is a link to the `comtypes` package: https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/#properties-with-arguments-named-properties
Looking at the examples it suggests you should try passing the array as  `condition.Text = ('Foo','Bar')`.

Comment: @DS_London I get the same results as my error above if I use ```condition.Text = ('Foo','Bar')```

Comment: I tried your original code with the [] brackets. It worked fine, so the problem could be in the python wrapper that comtypes generates behind the scenes. I didn't have the comtypes package so pip installed it (v1.1.10 on Python 3.7): so all my python wrappers were newly generated. Maybe try two things: (a) upgrade comtypes, and/or (b) try clearing the interface cache. If you put in the line `print(comtypes.client.gen_dir)` it will tell you where these wrappers are stored. Deleting that directory will force comtypes to recreate the wrappers, which might solve your issue.

Comment: @DS_London It was my version of python. I installed the latest the other day which was 3.10 and when I uninstalled and switched to 3.7 like you said you were using, it worked fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by downgrading python version from 3.10 to 3.7. 3.10 version seems to be new and still has some issues that needs to be worked out.

Comment: You could try using the `win32com` package instead of comtypes: It does the same thing, but maybe works better with Python 3.10?

Comment: @DS_London I can try it as an experiment in the future, for now I am happy to have a working solution. This isn’t ever going to be production code so for now I didn’t mind downgrading. Thank you again for the help!